# remove duplicate list after using zip()

Tags: python, list, duplicates, zip

```
one=['nlo_90', 'nlo_90', 'nhi_88']
two=['12', '12', '84']
three=[['a','a','b','c'], ['a','a','b','c'], ['b','g','g','b']]
new_three=[list(dict.fromkeys(q)) for q in three]

z=zip(one,two,new_three)
for a,b,c in z:
        c_str = ', '.join(c)
        print(f'{a}, {b}, {c_str}')
```

I need to remove duplicate data after i combine the lists using `zip()`

the output from above code is

```
nlo_90, 12, a, b, c
nlo_90, 12, a, b, c
nhi_88, 84, b, g
```

my desired output is

```
nlo_90, 12, a, b, c
nhi_88, 84, b, g
```

I tried to code  this  `new=list(dict.fromkeys(z))`  to remove duplicate but it shows error

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: The issue is you are using `list()` in `new_three=[list(dict.fromkeys(q)) for q in three]`, just change this to a `tuple()` and you will be able to do `dict.fromkeys(z)`

Answer (score 0):

### This Will Surely At Any Cost Give The Desired Output.

```py
one = ['nlo_90', 'nlo_90', 'nhi_88']
two = ['12', '12', '84']
three = [['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'g', 'g', 'b']]
new_three = [list(dict.fromkeys(q)) for q in three]

z = zip(set(one), two, new_three)

res = []

for a, b, c in z:
    c_str = ', '.join(c)
    res.append(f'{a}, {b}, {c_str}')

for res in reversed(sorted(res)):
    print(res)
```

### Output

```
nlo_90, 12, a, b, c
nhi_88, 12, a, b, c
```

Comment: thanks but it seems the output is not the same like my desired output

Comment: @qwe what's the diff ?

Comment: the second line in your output does not match with what i want.  here is the 2nd line of my desired output 'nhi_88, 84, b, g' meanwhile yours is 'nhi_88, 12, a, b, c'

Comment: @qwe i have updated my answer please check if the answer gives the desired output.

Comment: `set(one)` doesn't guarantee, you could use `dict.from_keys(one)` but then this only uses `one` to determine duplicate data.

Comment: @qwe did you check my given answer ? it solves that problem

Comment: PLEASE! Check the answer that has been posted @qwe.